# HQL query for getting some items in one to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I've searched all around internet and I didn't find my answer.

I have a oneToMany relation between two classes and I want to get a portion of the list.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
class Author {
     @Id
     private Long id;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
     private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="book")
class Book {

    @Column
    private Integer year;

    @Column
    private Integer position;

}
```

And I want to get all Books with a specific year and inferior to a specific position from a specific author

```
@Query(From Book b where b.year=:year and b.position<:position and b.authorId=:id)
List<Book> getAllBooks(Integer year, Integer position, Long id)
```

and I tried also

```
@Query(From Book b where b.year=:year and b.position<:position and b.id in (select a.books.id from author a where a.id:=id)
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: can you post your db structure

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set up the query with JPQL, to me it looks like it should be...

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.year = :year and b.position < :position and b.authorId = :id")
```

#### Update

Sorry -- I answered earlier by copying and modifying your first example.  I missed the join.

This might work...

```
@Query("SELECT a.books b FROM Author a WHERE b.year = :year AND b.position < :position AND a.authorId = :id")
```

You could also try this one this...

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.year = :year AND b.position < :position AND b IN (SELECT a.books FROM Author a WHERE a.id = :id")
```

Comment: I get this exception : Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: authorId of: Book

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. I had a sql error. But i wrote a jpqlQuery in my service and it worked. Thank you for your time